# verify linear independence of solutions of ODE

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to verify linear independence of three solutions of ODE, which are$$\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\0 \end{bmatrix} e^{t}, \begin{bmatrix}1\\-1\\1 \end{bmatrix} e^{t}, \begin{bmatrix}1\\-1\\1 \end{bmatrix} e^{2t}.$$
Plugging in $t=0$ and $t=1$ we can immediately find that only when $c_{1} = c_{2} = c_{3} = 0$  can we have  $$\begin{cases}c_{1}e^t +c_{2}e^t+c_{3}e^{2t}=0 \\c_{1}e^t -c_{2}e^t-c_{3}e^{2t}=0\\0 +c_{2}e^t+c_{3}e^{2t}=0\end{cases}$$ holds for $\forall t$.

But since the determinant of linear independent vectors would be not zero, the matrix made up with these three vectors should not have determinant equal to zero. I made the matrix and found that $$Det(\begin{bmatrix}e^t&e^t&e^{2t}\\e^t&-e^t&-e^{2t}\\0&e^t&e^{2t} \end{bmatrix}) = 0.$$

I don't know where it goes wrong, If vectors are linear independent, their determinant should be not equal to zero.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Notice that the given functions cannot be solutions of a linear homogeneous systems of ODEs of the form $\dot{\mathbf{x}}=A(t)\mathbf{x}$: the second and the third take the same value at $t=0$, which contradicts the uniqueness of IVP.

Comment: "we can immediately find that only ...": no, for any $t$, including $0$, $(0,1,-1)$ is a solution.

Answer (score 1):

There is no contradiction; the mistake you made is a subtle one. In the statement

> "But since the determinant of linear independent vectors would be not zero"

you implicitly (but incorrectly) assumed that functions being linearly independent implies that for all $t$ the values of the function evaluated at $t$ still remain linearly independent. This is false.

To illustrate this point further,
let $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be defined by $f(t) = e^t$, and let $g: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be defined by $g(t) = e^{2t}$. We say $f$ and $g$ are linearly independent functions if and only if we have the following equality of sets: 
\begin{equation}
\left\{(c_1,c_2)\in \mathbb{R^2}: \text{for all } t \in \mathbb{R}, \quad c_1f_1(t) + c_2f_2(t) = 0 \right\} = \left\{ (0,0) \right\}.
\end{equation}

And it is easy to verify that with the particular $f$ and $g$ as above, this equality holds; i.e $f$ and $g$ are linearly independent functions.

**But this does not imply** that for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$, $f(t)$ and $g(t)$ are linearly independent. In fact this couldn't be further from the truth, we actually have that
for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$, $f(t)$ and $g(t)$ are linearly dependent (because $f(t)$ and $g(t)$ are non-zero numbers; hence there is a constant of proportionality between them).

I hope I made the distinction between the two concepts clear.

Comment: @ peek-a-boo: if $x_1,...,x_n$ are solutions of the system $x'=Ax$, where $A$ is a real $n \times n$- matrix and if $L$ is the  the vector space of all solutions of the system, then we have: $x_1,...,x_n$ are linearly independent in $L \iff x_1(t),...., x_n(t)$ are   linearly independent in $ \mathbb R^n$ for all $t \iff$ there is some $t$ such that $x_1(t),...., x_n(t)$ are   linearly independent in $ \mathbb R^n$ .

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Now I understand that to be linearly independent we don't need $f(t)$ and $g(t)$ to satisfy the requirement for all $t$. But does this implies that using determinant could only tell us nothing? From what I understand, determinant equals to zero implies that there would be an non-trivial solution. So if  for individual $t$ it wouldn't tell us anything then the determinant would not tell us anything either.

Comment: @Fred, The OP didn't specify that the system of ODE's being solved was of the form $x' = Ax$ (although I guess the presence of exponentials made that a very plausible assumption).  But, I do understand the reasoning you presented in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Let $ x_1(t)=\begin{bmatrix}1\\-1\\1 \end{bmatrix} e^{t}$ and $x_2(t)= \begin{bmatrix}1\\-1\\1 \end{bmatrix} e^{2t}.$

Suppose that $x_1$ and $x_2$ are solutions of a system $x'=Ax$, where $A$ is a real $3 \times 3$ - matrix.

From $x_1'=Ax_1$ we see that $\begin{bmatrix}1\\-1\\1 \end{bmatrix}=A \begin{bmatrix}1\\-1\\1 \end{bmatrix}$, and from $x_2'=Ax_2$ we get $2 \begin{bmatrix}1\\-1\\1 \end{bmatrix}=A \begin{bmatrix}1\\-1\\1 \end{bmatrix}$, a contradiction.

Conclusion: something went wrong, $x_1$ and $x_2$ are not solutions of the same system $x'=Ax$.

Comment: You are right, this is not a solution of a linear system of ODE. Sorry, I didn't check this. But still, these three vectors are linear independent. Could you explain why their determinant can be identically zero?

Answer (score 0):

If $c_1=0$ and $t=0$, a single equation in two unknowns remains.

Comment: Could you please talk more about that? From what I got is $c_{2}*e^{t} + c_{3}*e^{2t}=0.$

Comment: @ChrisXU: ooops, very sorry, only for $t=0$.

Comment: You are right. What am I thinking... Only plugging in $t=0$ can not give us the answer.